# Unity3D fps weapon pickup/switch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a weaponholder object within weapons. On my weaponholder object I have a script to switch weapons. Now I don't know how to combine of with a weapon pick-up systen. Any ideas?

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

One good advice I can give you is to use scriptable objects for all your weapons and have a list of all the ones you collected.

You might find useful to create a scriptable object for the weapons with all the info it holds such as mesh, fire rate and others and just read the data from it.

This way you can switch the weapons by reading the data from the SO and pick-up the weapons by adding a SO to the list.

You can find more information about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vmRwLYWNRo